# When did Europeans make Sunday rather than Saturday the seventh day?

Tags: calendar

In the United States, calendars that list a week in one line are typically formatted like this:

```
S M T W T F S
```

Sunday is the first day of the week and Saturday is the seventh. That conforms to a tradition that goes back at least to ancient Jews long before Christianity.

If I understand correctly, people in Europe now regard Monday as the first day and Sunday as the seventh. The calendars are thus formatted:

```
M T W T F S S
```

Was it during the 20th century that Europeans adopted this convention?

(Additionally, some African countries consider Saturday the first day.)

Comment: Now I find this: "The origin of this custom is involved in obscurity. It was not borrowed from the Egyptians, as the week of seven days closing with a day of rest was unknown to them." http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/13287b.htm

Comment: I just want to mention that saturday is the first week day not only in africa but in most arabic and islamic countries

Comment: I've deleted the part of the question about a possible Egyptian origin of Saturday as the seventh day, since all I could think of as a reason for it is that I thought I might have read it in the _Catholic Encyclopedia_'s article titled "Sabbath", but that source seems to contradict it.

Comment: I also have a vague impression that Protestantism may be a big part of the reason for considering Sunday the seventh day. But that may be only as reliable as what I thought about a possible Egyptian origin. I few years ago I bought a calendar and found when I got home that it formatted each month with Monday rather than Sunday in the first column, which is certainly different from what is typical and standard, and in an internet forum I reported that that had happened, using as the subject line for the posting "The ultimate triumph of Protestantism".

Comment: Not an answer, but [this video](http://www.medievalists.net/2013/03/the-medieval-calendar/) implies that days of the week were just not important in the middle ages.  Though it does appear to have the week starting on Sunday.  I suspect the answer has to do when the modern calendar format appeared.  I suspect it's fairly recent.

Comment: AFAIK, it is to do with the secularisation of society in the late 20th century. With the decline of Christianity, coupled with multi-culturalism, the preeminence of Sunday as the most important day of the week declined, to be replaced with Monday as the first *business* day. When I was growing up in the UK in the 50s/60s , Sunday was still the first day of the week.

Comment: The Hindus consider Ravi (equivalent to our Sunday), and the early Chinese calenders also refer to it as "First Star" associated with the Sun.  it is interesting to note the association of the first day of the week with the Sun has been around for quite possibly long as the concept of the week has.
I think references to Christian/Jewish traditions miss the forest for the trees. Its association has been around far, far, far longer than that.

Comment: @TheHonRose : Are calendars in Britain today usually formatted with Monday in the first column and Sunday in the last?

Comment: @StevenBurnap : The video you cite says explicitly that the days of the week were identified by the letters A through G. But strangely, the narrator says "Sunday through Monday", which makes no sense.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, they are - I've just checked my 2017 diary (calendar) and it starts Monday. In some small pocket diaries, Saturday and Sunday share a slot - as I said, partly privileging the business week.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I took that to mean that "A" was Sunday, and that "A' was shorthand.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find much other info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Sunday is the first day of the week and Saturday is the seventh. That conforms to a tradition that goes back at least to ancient Jews long before Christianity.

It should be noted that other ways of counting and grouping days *did* exist concurrently to Jewish / Christian traditions. Egypt used the [decan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decan) (ten days), the Roman calendar used the [nundial cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_calendar#Nundinal_cycle) of *eight* days to a "week", the [French Republican Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Republican_Calendar) used ten day weeks as well (with the tenth day replacing the Sunday "as the day of rest and festivity"). The [Soviet calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_calendar) was a mess, with five day weeks (with the "day off" being assigned differently to worker groups to have 80% of the work force in the factories *each* day), and later, six day weeks (with the *last* day of the week being the "day off" for everyone).

And quoting from [Sunday or Monday?](http://www.cjvlang.com/Dow/SunMon.html) (which I would recommend reading in full as it showcases several, sometimes differing, views):

> According to Webster's Ninth New Collegiate Dictionary (1983), the term 'weekend', first recorded in 1878, refers to 'the period between the close of one working or business or school week and the beginning of the next'. This concept firmly places Sunday at the end of the week.

Also, Wikipedia "[Workweek and weekend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend#History)" states that...

> The present-day concept of the relatively longer 'week-end' first arose in the industrial north of Britain in the early part of nineteenth century[[1]](https://www.etymonline.com/word/weekend) and was originally a voluntary arrangement between factory owners and workers allowing Saturday afternoon off from 2pm in agreement that staff would be available for work sober and refreshed on Monday morning.[2] The Oxford English Dictionary traces the first use of the term weekend to the British magazine Notes and Queries in 1879.[[8]](http://www.smh.com.au/national/the-origin-of-the-weekend-20150807-giu3ay.html)

So precedent existed.

---

Mention was made in comments of the German DIN 1355 (1943) and DIN 1355-1 (1975), the former identifying the beginning of the week as "Sunday 0:00" and the latter identifying Monday as the first day of the week. This would bracket the "when" of the change, for Germany at least, as "sometime between 1943 and 1975".

Comment: This narrows it down somewhat, but we don't yet have a smoking gun.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I fear if you are looking for a set date when all the people sat down and decided, "you know what, let's shuffle the weekdays around a bit", you will be searching in vain. This is something that became custom over time, some switched earlier, some later, and eventually ISO 8601 codified it.

Comment: I'm not looking for a decree that effected all of Europe as of a specified date, but I would think a far more specific, if lengthier, answer would be possible.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Well, you ask about "the Europeans" as if they were a single entity. Not even all the calendar makers within one of Europe's many countries are a single entity. Can you be a bit more specific as to what you are expecting in an answer?

Answer (score 15):

- In the 1970s the day numbering was standardized worldwide, culminating in an UN decision. The current version of the standard is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Some countries were more timely than others in adopting this standard.
- In Christian interpretation the day after Sabbath (i.e. Sunday) was seen as the first day of the week (e.g. chapter 16 of the Gospel of Mark).
- Early in the Christian era Sunday became the rest/prayer day of the week. Supposedly that was Constantine, but I didn't hunt down Latin sources. That made Monday the first workday of the week.
- In German civil law, due dates falling on a Sunday or Saturday are shifted to the next Monday (§193 BGB). In that sense, the weekend belongs to the previous week. Not sure which other European nations have similar rules.

Comment: What do you mean by "the current practice"? Do you mean treating Sunday as the seventh day? I don't think anyone would dispute that Saturday is the seventh day according to religious traditions based on Genesis.

Comment: There must have been some customary practice before the ISO standard was promulgated. Your answer says nothing about how that evolved.

Comment: Well, except the Biblical "Sabbath" was in fact Saturday (actually Sundown Friday to Sundown Saturday). But I'll agree it sort of anachronistically goes back and makes that part of the Bible make sense again to most Christians.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Must there have been?  Perhaps it just wasn't something anyone cared about before.

Comment: @StevenBurnap : How would you make a calendar for a month without following some convention in this matter?

Comment: By not laying them out in a grid by week, but rather with one line per day.  That seems to be how most Medieval calendars worked.

Comment: @StevenBurnap : Are you suggesting that before the ISO standard was established in the 1970s, calendars in Europe were formatted the way medieval calendars were? Are you perhaps under the impression that medieval times ended during or after the 1970s?

Comment: I've just down-voted this answer because of the lack of any response to my comment from "o.m."

Comment: @MichaelHardy In Eastern Europe Sunday is considered to be the last day of the week. I first heard about the American calendar system long after I studied English-it took some time to process.

Comment: "Some countries were more timely than others in adopting this standard." Has it occurred to you that a country's failure to adopt this standard may result not from untimeliness, but rather from rejection of the standard?

Comment: @Greg : What you call "the American system" is of course not American in origin at all; obviously it was brought from Europe, which ultimately got it from ancient Jews.

Comment: As revised two days ago, this answer leaves most of the questions unanswered. An ISO standard would not introduce a new convention but would codify existing conventions. So this must of have been standard in much of Europe before the 1970s. The fourth point is somewhat vague in that it doesn't say what sort of "due dates" are intended. Whether this means dates for payment of debts or something else is unclear. However, in the United States, where Sunday is conventionally the first day of the week, many things are shifted to Monday if counting days would put them on a Saturday or a Sunday, so..

Comment: ...that doesn't mean Monday is considered the first day of the week. Also the linked Wikipedia article says this ISO standard was promulgated in 1988, not in the 1970s. The main question remains unanswered: When did Europeans adopt this practice? From the way they write about it on the internet, they seem unaware that they change their former practice.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, for Germany DIN 1355-1 in 1975 set Monday as the first day of the week, superseding DIN 1355 which stated that the week begins on Sunday. As to awareness, few people care which week a Sunday belongs to -- counting matters in business and administrative contexts and there Sunday does not count, see the BGB reference above.

Comment: DIN 1355 dating back to 1943, stating that weeks "begin on Sunday 0:00", so for official "ruling" in Germany at least the "when" can be bracketed with "sometime between 1943 and 1975".